# Can't disable csrutil

Tags: macos, dual-boot

I want to disable SIP with the command `csrutil disable` on my OS X 10.11.5.
I tried it many times, got in the recovery mode and typed in `csrutil disable`.
I got the message:

> Successfully disabled System Integrity Problem. Please restart the machine for the changes take effect

Everytime after restarting, `csrutil status` doesn't change. It's still enabled.

I actually tried it in recovery mode with `/usr/bin/csrutil disable` always the same and after restart it's enabled again..

BTW: if you need outputs of the commands, tell me!

Comment: Have you tried resetting the NVRAM? Sometimes the settings could get corrupted.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yes I reset it now 2 times, and after that I enter 'csrutil clear' also and reboot many times again. But it seems to stay enabled ..

Comment: Have you tried it in single-user mode?

Comment: @JacobF. Disabling SIP must be done in Recovey Mode, not in single-user mode

Comment: @patrix Actually you can boot into recovery with single user mode with `Command+R+S` from my knowledge.